# If + would have + past participle

Tags: conditional-constructions

*If you would have told me you needed a ride, I would have left earlier.*

I have very vague awareness of the fact that there is a special type of conditional clauses using this pattern: If + would have + past participle. Could you please explain to me how my exemplary sentence differs from *If you had told me you needed a ride, I would have left earlier.*

Answer (score 1):

The technically correct way to say it is:

> If you had told me you needed a ride, I would have left earlier.

As you noted in your question. I would say that formal usages still stick to this and never use "if you would have told ...".

However, there is a way in which there can be "would have" in the conditional:

> I you would have just one piece of cake, I would be delighted. (*Where the cake is the one I baked, of course.*)

Answer (score 0):

As someone else already pointed out, this is not a valid conditional form.

There are three conditional forms, each one with its own functions and nuances:

**First conditional: If + present => future simple**

This form is expressing a *probable* outcome in the future. For example:

*"If you study, you will pass the exam."*

The implication is that probably you will study, therefore probably you will pass the exam when the time comes.

**Second conditional: If + past simple => would + verb**

This form is expressing an *improbable* outcome in the future. For example:

*"If you studied, you would pass."*

The implication here is that you are not studying, therefore you will probably fail the exam when the time comes.

**Third conditional: If + past perfect => would have + past participle**

This form is expressing an *impossible* outcome in the past. For example:

*"If you had studied, you would have passed."*

The implication here is that the exam has already been, you have failed it, and the reason is in the if-clause.

Answer (score 0):

The way to invoke the *if* clause with *would* is by using *if only.*

We use ***if only + would + base form*** when we want the behaviour of someone or something to change:

> *If only you **wouldn't speak** so slowly.*
>   *If only it **would snow**.*

As you were told, the conditionals are formed by differrent structures. Even though there are more forms called **mixed conditionals** which are a mixture of the second and third type:

> *If you **had** had lunch earlier, you **wouldn't be** hungry now.* (I didn't have lunch earlier, so I'm hungry now.)

There are many ways to create mixed conditional forms.

Answer (score 0):

> If you would have told me you needed a ride, I would have left earlier.

This sentence is incorrect, because for conditional you **never** use if + would in the same part.

> If you had told me you needed a ride, I would have left earlier.

We use the third conditional, to talk about things in the past that **didn't** happen but we **wish**, it happend.